# Vault server token login doesn't work as per lease time

Tags: hashicorp-vault, secret-key

We are using Hashicorp Vault with Consul and Filesystem as storage, facing issue on login every time my token duration is infinity but still ask for token need to be sealed for every few hours with again login?

config.hcl:

```
    `ui = true

storage "consul" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
  path    = "vault"
}

backend "file" {
  path = "/mnt/vault/data"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "127.0.0.1:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

telemetry {
  statsite_address = "127.0.0.1:8125"
  disable_hostname = true
}`
```

**Token lookup:**

```
 Key                  Value
      • -----
token                **********
token_accessor       ***********
token_duration       ∞
token_renewable      false
token_policies       ["root"]
identity_policies    []
policies             ["root"]
```